# String version of array to ArrayList

Tags: java

I have an a string like

`String myString = "[\"One\", \"Two\"]";`

I am struggling with figuring out how to turn it into an ArrayList with values "One" and "Two"

I tried using `JSONArray` but it doesn't seem to work how I expected

---

EDIT:" When I print my string it actually prints without the \

`System.out.println(myString)` prints:

`["One", "Two"]`

I tried

`JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(stringCharactersArray);`

and got that the constructor can't take a string. I am using JSONArray from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: If it prints like this `["One", "Two"]` this is not JSON formated string @es3735746

Comment: Gotcha...so what are my options for a string like this. I know I could split on spaces and manually remove the quotes but that seems so not elegant

Comment: @Shantanu The provided string `["One", "Two"]` is perfectly valid JSON and can pe parsed as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code and it's working fine BUT instead of using `com.googlecode.json-simple` I used `org.json.JSONArray`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

and the code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String val = "[\"One\", \"Two\"]";
        
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(val);  
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println( jsonArr.getString( i ) );
        }
    }
}
```

this prints:

> One
>
> Two

It seems that it doesn't need the input string json array to be exactly formed as standard as:

`{"arr": ["One", "two"]}`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *parse* your string with json-simple, then do the following:

```
String myString = "[\"One\", \"Two\"]";
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse(myString);
System.out.println(array);
```

This prints out:

```
["One","Two"]
```

If you want to have it as a `java.util.List` then simply do the following:

```
String myString = "[\"One\", \"Two\"]";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(myString.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(", "));
System.out.println(list);
```

This prints out:

```
["One", "Two"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. I used "org.json"

```
String myString = "[\"One\", \"Two\"]";
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(myString);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(jsonArray.getString(i));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It would print.

```
One
Two
```